# Echo xml result from wcf service in php?

Tags: php, wcf

I have a WCF Operation GetColors which returns a list of colors as GetColorsResult.  I am getting the result fine, but how do I loop through GetColorsResult in php and echo each element?

I am doing:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/plain');

echo "WCF Test\r\n\r\n";

// Create a new soap client based on the service's metadata (WSDL)
$client = new SoapClient('http://localhost:8181/Colors.svc?wsdl',array(
                         'login' => "test", 'password' => "test"));


 $retval = $client->GetColors();


 //Need to loop throuh $retval here

 echo $retval->GetColorsResult; //This throws error.




?>
```

Is there way to control the name of the result, for example, I did not specify WCF to return GetColorsResult, it appended Result to my method call.  Likewise, it appends Response to GetColors for the Response (GetColorsResponse)

Output when doing print_r($retval):

```
stdClass Object
(
    [GetColorsResult] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Color] => Array
                (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [Code] => 1972
                        [Name] => RED
                    )

                [1] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [Code] => 2003
                        [Name] => BLUE
                    )

                [2] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [Code] => 2177
                        [Name] => GREEN
                    )
               )
          )
      )
```

Comment: You might want to add some of the code you already have... (didn't downvote by the way)

Comment: I will be glad to add code.  Don't know why the downvote, I am not familiar with php.

Comment: Could you try print_r($retval) and post the output, too?

Comment: @TerrenceJackson,  I updated my post to show print_r($retval) results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

regarding to your print_r this should give you all the values:

```
<?php
$colorResult = $retval->GetColorsResult;
foreach($colorResult->Color as $color){
  echo $color->Code . " " . $color->Name . "<br />";
}
?>
```

is this what you needed?

BR,

TJ

EDIT: 
If you just need it for debugging purposes, you should use print_r. 
Have a look here: [print_r PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/de/function.print-r.php)

Comment: I did exactly what you said and it doesn't throw an error, but it just prints out 11223330000, but I am just doing: echo $color->Name + "<br/>"

Comment: I removed the <br /> and it worked, but now everything is on one line.

Comment: I had to do a . instead of a + for concatenation. Thanks.

Comment: <br/> is the linebreak in html. What exactly do you want for the outup? Something like <Name> <Name> or <Name>;<Name>

Comment: I fixed it but I had to do . instead of the +

Comment: Oh, sry. You're right. I was in the wrong language there ... ;) I change it. Thx for the remark ;)

Comment: No problem, I am used to the + as well.